# Fade out old flash message before fading in new one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new to jquery. I have a form which performs a calculation, and returns the result in a flash message. My goal behavior is:

1. upon first form submit, flash message containing results fades in
2. on subsequent submissions, the flash message containing the old results fades out, and then the new flash message fades in.

I am confused how to do this because obviously both the old and the new results have the same id.

Currently only the fade in is working.

jquery:

```
$(function() {
  $(".btn-primary").click(function() {
    $("#diagnosis").fadeOut("slow");
  });
$('#diagnosis').delay(0).fadeIn('normal', function() {
  $(this).delay(2500);
  });
});
```

CSS

```
#diagnosis { display:none; }
```

Comment: Hello Dylan, I think I can help you with that if you could give me some additional info your question is a little bit confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain fadeIn and fadeOut animations in Jquery. Note that you can also pass a complete function to either animation, such as `$('#result').fadeOut('fast', () => {})`. This ensures we only update the result when it fully disappears, then the new result will immediately fade in with the updated value. See more reference [here](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/#fadeOut-duration-complete).

```js
let arr = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

$('form').on("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  // mock calculated result 
  let genIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
  let resultVal = arr[genIdx];
 
  $('#result').fadeOut('fast', () => {
      $('#result').text(resultVal);
  }).fadeIn('fast');

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
      <p id="result"></p>
      <button type="subimit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Janice, thank you for your answer! I realize that my initial question was missing some important information: the result of the form is actually returned by a python function in flask. I guess I first need to go and research how to use jquery to call a server side function from flask. Then I can return to this topic.

Comment: @Dylan Sure, let me know if you have any question related to this part later on :)

Comment: Hi Janice, I resolved my other issue and returned to this topic. Your solution works perfectly. Thank you for showing me how to chain animations in Jquery!